# Problems with debugging using gdb

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, mingw

I've got a problem with **gdb** debugger. My console app shows me incorrect action results (some trash instead of normal string which I've got from XML ater the parsing) if I run it under a debugger plus I get SIGINT ( I don't output eol character and don't hit ctrl+c). Running my app with no attached debugger (just double click on .exe or Run menu from IDE) shows me correct results. What is the problem?

**Some Info**:
Windows 7 Pro Sp1 x86
gdb 7.3.1 (MinGW) and gcc 4.6.2 (MinGW)
Eclipse 3.7.1

[Here](http://paste.kde.org/440834/13318458/) is a **gdb trace**.
At [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arfh9.png) you can see the settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have some memory corruption in your application and and they become visible when you use the debugger. In order to solve the problem we need to take a look on your source code.

Comment: I found and fix the memory corruption and it is no some garbage in debug results - all is ok, but I still got a message Quit (expect signal SIGINT when the program is resumed).